# show picture with special character name

Tags: subfig

how i can show picture in latex but with special character file name

```
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{pictures/datasets/0107339559387-84_87-136&496_317&565-321&542_157&562_144&510_308&490-0_0_17_33_23_32_31-152-32.jpg }
        \label{fig:C}

\end{figure}
```

**it shows this warning**

> File ended while scanning use of @subfloat.

Comment: You are missing a second  closing brace at the end.

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: `[!htb]` unrelated to your question, but why prevent this being placed on a page of figures? (no `p`)